# Boot screen does not show Win XP

Tags: boot

Today I deleted my Mint 11 partitions to create un-allocated space, in which I clean installed Ubuntu 12.04.

I originally had Windows XP, Mint 11 & Mint 12 working fine with all three showing up on boot screen. Sequence of installs was, XP first followed by Mint 11 and lastly Mint 12. On installing Mint 12, booted into Mint 11, used sudo grub-install /dev/sda followed by sudo update-grub. Subsequent restart came up with all OSs showing on the boot screen.

NOW try as I may, I am unable to get Windows XP to show in the boot screen after installing Ubuntu.

Hope someone can help me. All the OSs are installed in sda.

Comment: Try `sudo grub-mkconfig` in gnome-terminal.

Answer (score 0):

If you can boot into Ubuntu, try sudo update-grub  this will show you what OS's you have installed that grub can find.  If it does not find Windows please ask again.  Does the NTFS partition show up OK in gparted?

Comment: ntfs shows up OK on gparted. Can also access ntfs partition from Ubuntu